Kiosk mode with browser/on-screen-keyboard/filemanager
I want to build a kiosk system which:

will run a browser (Chrome)
will run an on-screen keyboard
will enable a user to download files via that browser and store them on a USB stick/disk
does not require (and preferable not offer) other services (printing, other applications, etc)

My current version installs a slimmed-down Gnome, and autostarts the browser after boot up, and enables the on-screen keyboard. The autostarting and enabling of the on-screen keyboard have been set up manually (not in the NixOS config).
However, we want the system to be as limited as possible. Hence, I am looking for a better way. Preferably fully configured in NixOS. If using Gnome, its single-application mode (https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/lockdown-single-app-mode.html.en) would be preferred.
I do not mind switching to another Window Manager (Wayland and/or X11).
Using home-manager is no problem.
Who can help me with examples and/or pointers to get such system up.
I have also posted the question to reddit, but that did not lead to workable results (https://www.reddit.com/r/NixOS/comments/1fkjgiw/kiosk_mode_with_browseronscreenkeyboardfilemanager/).

You can use cage + firefox (which allows you to select a destination folder for downloaded files) + udisks which automounts usb sticks. You will lack an option to unmount usb sticks, though, and I'm not sure about the virtual keyboard.

cage does not (yet) support on screen keyboards...
